# Deploying Mean stack webapp on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, npm, bower, mean

I have created a webapp based on the the Mean Stack( MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, NodeJS).  I had followed this tutorial on setting up AWS: https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1

I got to the point where they started their server.js file by just calling `node server.js`.  I do not have a server.js though.  In webstorm I run `grunt serve` and it launches everything.  On aws I run grunt serve and it just says cannot find bower components.  I also try to run bower install and it fails saying I do not have permission but when I run `sudo bower install` it says bower cannot be run with sudo.

I am not sure how to solve this issue.  Should I figure out how to use a server.js?

Any help wold be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm start instead of node server.js, if you have initialized the app using npm init.